# Find intersection point of two curves using numerical methods

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I am very new to Mathematica, and have only basic mathematics knowledge, so apologies in advance if any section of my question is ill-explained. Here goes:

My goal is to identify the intersection point of two curves. They look something like this:

```
y = (1/(1 + exp((0.2*x) - 14))) - (1/(1 + exp((0.2*x) - 11)))
```

and

```
y = (1/(1 + exp((0.2*x) - 17))) - (1/(1 + exp((0.2*x) - 14)))
```

The curves look like two overlapping Gaussian distributions.

I've learned that since the models are so complex I probably can't do substitution to find their intersection point, and instead need to use numerical methods. Does anyone here know how to tell Mathematica to try a range of numbers and find the one that matches their intersection point?

Comment: See the tutorial [Numerical Equation Solving](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalEquationSolving.html), or enter "equation solving" into the search field of the Help > Wolfram Documentation window and explore the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSolve[
       (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 14])) - (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 11])) == 
       (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 17])) - (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 14])), x]
```

{{x -> 70.}}

```
Plot[{(1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 14])) - (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 11])), 
      (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 17])) - (1/(1 + Exp[(0.2 x) - 14]))}, 
    {x, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use exact numbers in expressions or use [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

```
f1[x_] = 1/(1 + Exp[x/5 - 14]) - 1/(1 + Exp[x/5 - 11]);

f2[x_] = 1/(1 + Exp[x/5 - 17]) - 1/(1 + Exp[x/5 - 14]);
```

Using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) with a constraint

```
sol = Solve[{f1[x] == f2[x], 0 < x < 100}, x][[1]]

(* {x -> 70} *)
```

Verifying solution

```
f1[x] == f2[x] /. sol

(* True *)
```

Using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) with constraint

```
sol2 = Reduce[{f1[x] == f2[x], 0 < x < 100}, x]

(* x == 70 *)
```